# Running on_exit task - Azure App Service (Windows) and Python

Tags: python, azure

Our API runs on Azure App Service (Windows), our code written in Python.
So the Azure App Service always crashes then we just need to commit a code from our GitHub repo to make it alive again.

"2019-04-14 01:33:41.535441: Running on_exit tasks"

We've turned on the "always on" already.

Here's my web.config setup:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="main.app"/>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\repository"/>
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>
    <add key="WSGI_RESTART_FILE_REGEX" value="" />
  </appSettings>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\Python364x86\python.exe|D:\home\Python364x86\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What's your real question? Does it also not work after enabled `always on`? I do not get your point about `always creashes` and `make it alive again`. If for crash, please post its related error information. Or just not alive, the `always on` feature should keep it alive to avoid to sleep for reducing resource consumption when no accessing in a long time.

Comment: Hi Peter Pan, it's definitely working but there random crashes happening. although today, we found out that the issue occurred due to our token assignment. Thanks for answering.

Comment: If you figured out how to solve your problem please consider adding it as an answer. That way it can help other people who may be having the same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So we resolved the issue by reviewing how we assign tokens when execute our "API". Some of our tokens are expiring and when our app execute "GET" or "POST"(FROM REACT to Python on Azure App Service) the token was expired already. The expired token causes the 500 Internal Error.

That's why we thought that the server is crashing. Although the logs from WfastCgi did not give us the whole picture of why we are encountering the issue but at least it gave us a warning and signal what to check.